# Modificacion en tiempo real de codigo

Tags: lenguaje-agnóstico

Siempre me he preguntado aunque pienso que es poco probable aun asi seria interesante conocer si hay algo que se asimile. ¿Existe algun lenguaje de programacion que se pueda modificar mientras este esta en funcionamiento?

Comment: a que te refieres cuando este en funcionamiento, mientras se ejecuta?

Comment: La cuestión no es sólo el lenguaje; la arquitectura del ordenador debe soportarlo. Algunos SO distinguen al cargar páginas de memoria para código y para datos, con las primeras normalmente siendo no modificables. Esto permite que, por ejemplo, si hay una librería que se use mucho, se cargue está sólo una vez en memoria en vez de una vez por proceso. También está relacionado con el código reentrante (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing)#Rules_for_reentrancy).

Comment: Me refieron mientras se este ejecutando el proceso secuencial comun

Comment: @AsahiSara Si a lo que te refieres es poder editarlo sin tener que parar el servidor, en este caso, serian aquellos lenguajes no compilados. Por ejemplo, tu puedes editar el PHP, HTML y JS de tu página mientras el usuario sigue navegando. ¿Recomendable? Claro que no! Imaginate que te casca... :P

Answer (score 2):

Depende de lo que se entienda por modificar en tiempo real:

Javascript tiene la función [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/eval) que permite inyectar código en cualquier momento: un programa en Javascript podría recibir datos de un fichero o de una respuesta HTTP y añadirlos como código a ejecutar:

```js
function ejemplo() {
 return 'hola';
}

console.log(ejemplo())

//imaginemos que hacemos una llamada ajax y obtenemos esta respuesta:

let respuesta="function ejemplo() { return 'adios';}"

eval(respuesta)
console.log(ejemplo());
```

Con Java, cuando estás depurando código, al detectar un error, puedes modificar las fuentes en cualquier IDE y los cambios se inyectarán ([se llama Hot Swapping y se puede hacer también en producción](https://dzone.com/articles/hot-swap-java-bytecode-on-runtime)). No estoy seguro si hay alguna limitación para que sea el propio programa el que busque y actualice su ejecutable, pero definitivamente podemos modificar los ejecutables.

De un modo menos radical (porque esa parte del código se para antes de modificarla), existen muchos programas que aceptan plugins en caliente: añaden librerías (un .jar en Java, por ejemplo, un .dll en .net) y las ejecutan cuando hace falta.

Answer (score 0):

Existe FireBase, ofrece base de datos en tiempo real, la aplicación puede estar en ejecución y se puede actualizar un TextView por ejemplo. Pero sería interesante modificar un color o algo así en tiempo real. Saludos